# How To Line Break Inside Code Tag In .slim

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

So I've been looking all up and down Google and I've got nothing. So can someone help?

I have my .slim file all set up and I'm trying to and a `pre` - `code` section with a line break in it...

```
pre
    code[class="language-markup" id="copyHTML-1"]
        = '<label for="name-1">Label</label>\
            <input id="name-1" type="text" name="name" required>'
```

The output is...

```
<label for="name-1">Label</label>\
<input id="name-1" type="text" name="name" required>
```

I get the line break but I get the trailing backslash. How do I get a link break in there with no trailing backslash?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you put a `<br>`?

Comment: A `<br>` won't work in this situation because I'm writing in a `<pre>` tag, doing so will show the `<br>` and not actually line break.

Comment: sorry, i've missed that -))

Comment: It's all good my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, line break in string is `"\n"` in Ruby, and `\n` must be placed in double quotes `""`, so you could try this:

```rb
= "<label for='name-1'>Label</label>\n
     <input id='name-1' type='text' name='name' required>"
```

Update part:

Or you could just use `slim` syntax:

```
label[for="name-1"]
  | Label
input#name-1[type="text" name="name" required]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but sadly it didn't work. I get an error when I compile

`/Users/sportas/Work Box/Markup_Library_Cut/input--text.slim:178: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting end-of-input
end;end;end;end`

Comment: @Satrop Could you just use slim syntax? Check the update part answer if you could.

Comment: Sorry, can't do that either. Because of the code being in a `code` - tag when you write in slim syntax at compile time that will get seen as... well... code, so on the front side all you see is the word "Label" as it was written in a `code` block.

Really do appreciate you helping!

Comment: Just in case, did you try to see what happens when remove the trailing backslash \ from the original code? And do you have to add the break line? Because the final HTML should work without the break line.

Comment: So if I do that I have to re-format the `slim` syntax to get a correct compile. Looks like this (sorry for the ugly formatting)  
`= '<label for="name-1">Label</label>'
     = '<input id="name-1" type="text" name="name" required>'`  
So doing this outputs this:  
`<label for="name-1">Label</label><input id="name-1" type="text" name="name" required>`  
Everything is on one line.

Comment: I just found a `html` to `slim` converter, you could try it with the final html to generate the right slim code. http://www.html2slim.net/

Comment: Thanks for that! But still no joy. Seeing as this was a test of a new way to build things I think I might be ditching the idea of using .slim and trying EJS.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to enable the Slim pretty-print feature, which indents nested tags on different lines.

For Rails, you could set this in an environment file., for example `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
# Indent html for pretty debugging and do not sort attributes
Slim::Engine.set_options pretty: true, sort_attrs: false
```

The Slim documentation has more info:
https://github.com/slim-template/slim#configuring-slim